How to load a Keras model without importing Keras in a Python desktop app?
I have a trained Keras model saved as model.h5, which I would normally load using keras.models.load_model("model.h5"). I'm currently developing a Python desktop application with a GUI and need to package it as a standalone .exe file.
The problem is that importing keras.models significantly increases the size of the .exe file beyond my size limit. I’m looking for a way to load and run the model.h5 file without including the entire Keras library in the final package.
Is there a way to load a .h5 model file without importing the keras.models module?
Alternatively, is there a tool or method to selectively include only the necessary parts of Keras when packaging the app, instead of bundling the entire library?
Environment:
Python version: 3.11.7
Keras and TensorFlow versions: Keras 2.15.0, TensorFlow 2.15
Packaging tool: PyInstaller

You may convert the TensorFlow model to ONNX and inference it using ONNX runtime: Getting Started Converting TensorFlow to ONNX

The short answer is no, Keras doesn't have "inference only slimmed down version of the library". You either need :

a full thing,
carve the library yourself intot the smallest subset that your model needs,
convert model to something else, e.g. you can use pure TensorFlow since Keras uses it underneath
deploy your model to a separate server, and then use your .exe to start said server and communicate with it

